# I keep getting a segmentation fault and I don't know why

Tags: c

I'm writing a linked list program in C and I'm stuck trying to write the linked list to a file. After the program asks the user what name they want to save the file under I enter the name and hit ENTER and then I get a segmentation fault and the program quits. I am lost trying to figure out why. The only thing I can think of is the `do..while` loop, but I use code like that elsewhere in my program and it works fine. Thanks in advance!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Inventory {
    int partID;
    int quantity;
    float price;
    struct Inventory *next;
};

void saveFile(struct Inventory**);

int main()
{
    struct Inventory *first = address location of first structure in list;

    saveFile(&first);

    return 0;
}

void saveFile (struct Inventory **firstPtr)
{
    struct Inventory *prev = NULL;
    char ext[5] = ".csv";
    char fileName[15];
    char c;

    FILE *fp;

    printf("   What would you like to save your linked list as, up to 14 characters: ");
    scanf("%s", fileName);
    strcat(fileName, ext);

    if((fp = fopen(fileName, "r")) != NULL) {
        printf("   File already exists. Would you like to overwrite? [Y/N] ");
        scanf("\n%c", &c);

        if(c == 'Y' || c == 'y') {
           fclose(fp);
           fp = fopen(fileName, "w+");
        } else {
           printf("   Would you like to add to the list? [Y/N] ");
           if(c == 'y' || c == 'Y') {
               fclose(fp);
               fp = fopen(fileName, "a");
           } else {
               fclose(fp);
               return;
           }
        }

    } else {
        fclose(fp);
        fp = fopen(fileName, "w+");
    }   

    do {
        prev = *firstPtr;
        fprintf(fp, "%d,%d,%f\n", prev->partID, prev->quantity, prev->price);
        prev = prev->next; 
    } while (prev->next != NULL); 

    fclose(fp);
}
```

Comment: Best advice: use a debugger

Comment: `prev = *firstPtr; prev->partID; ` that and the other accesses of `prev` are dereferencing an uninitialised pointer. `*firstPtr` is `first` from the `main` function which is uninitialised.

Comment: AFAICS, you've not initialized `first` in `main()`, and you use it in the function (where it is called `*firstPtr`) without initializing it yet (`prev = *firstPtr;`) which is probably why you're crashing.  You need to ensure it points somewhere valid — it appears that it should not be a null pointer that you pass to the function.

Comment: Read the comment. I just put first there so you could see where firstPtr came from. In the actual program which is more detailed `first` will have an address location stored in it.

Comment: I will edit it so that it is more apparent. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: What does the debugger tell you when you step through the code?

Comment: Can't stress enough: Use a debugger. At the very minimum it will tell you exactly which line of code is causing the seg fault. So we don't waste time trying to work out that very basic info that you can gather for yourself in less than 1 minute.  `while (prev->next != NULL);` is probably wrong. `prev` can be `NULL`.

Comment: `warning: ignoring return value of ‘scanf’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]` is all I get

Comment: `while(prev->next != NULL);` isn't wrong, I use that as a check with every loop that loops through my structure. for sorting, printing, and reading from a file.

Comment: Each node has not been allocated.

Comment: If `prev` was `NULL`, `prev->next` would be rong. It's better to put check loop check before, not after.

Comment: @Luke it's wrong.  Everyone is telling you the same. If you don't believe it then do proper debugging. With a debugger or some simple debug print statements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your loop does not guard against the first entry being possibly `NULL`, try using following to loop through a linked list:

```
while (prev) {
    fprintf(fp, "%d,%d,%f\n", prev->partID, prev->quantity, prev->price);
    prev = prev->next;
}
```

Comment: My program doesn't give the user the option to save unless there is at least one structure in the list.

Comment: I know, it's noted in your post, but you can never be for sure without robust testing.

Comment: The first entry does not need to be NULL for the problem to occur. Consider a list with one element. `prev = *firstPtr` will make `prev` point to the first element. `prev = prev->next;` will now set `prev` to NULL as  there is no next element. `while (prev->next != NULL)` then dereferences a NULL pointer.

Comment: That's true. I am going to edit the code and then I will come back with the results.

Comment: AH, I see! I see what was happening. Thank you all so much! I was checking prev->next after I set prev to NULL. I get it. Thank you, thank you!